# sp_executesql return id on insert in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a dynamic stored procedure that updates,inserts and deletes from specific table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Pj_Change
@Action Varchar(20),
@TableName Varchar(20),
@InsertQuery Nvarchar(max),
@UpdateQuery Nvarchar(max),
@Where Varchar(50)

AS   
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max);   

  SET NOCOUNT ON
  IF(@Action = 'UPDATE')
  SET @SQLString = 'UPDATE '+@TableName+' SET '+@UpdateQuery+' WHERE ('+@Where+')';
  ELSE IF(@Action = 'INSERT')
  SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO '+@TableName+' '+@InsertQuery + ';
  ELSE IF(@Action = 'DELETE')
  SET @SQLString = 'DELETE FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE ('+@Where+')';

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQLString

END
```

The problem is, than I try to add to this code `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get an ID of new row on insert, I get -1 in output.
The change that I make is:

```
@SQLString = 'INSERT INTO '+@TableName+' '+@InsertQuery + '; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()';
```

What do I need to change for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's ok, you shouldn't be using `scope_identity` anyway. You have more modern constructs, like:

```
update ... set ... output updated.id where ... -- same for insert and delete
```

You can either output the results in a table (not needed for a single insert) or use the simple form like above and have the `update` statement act as `select` and return the value.